# how to get list of all weeks

Tags: python

i tried something like this

```
year, week_num, day_num = date.today().isocalendar()
weeks = []
week_range_start = 1
week_range_end = 17
for i in range(week_range_start,week_range_end):
  curr_week = week_num - i
  str_week = str(curr_week) if len(str(curr_week)) == 2 else f'0{curr_week}'
  weeks.append(str(year) + str_week)
print(weeks)
```

my output looks something like this

```
['202114', '202113', '202112', '202111', '202110', '202109', '202108', '202107', '202106', '202105', '202104', '202103', '202102', '202101', '202100', '2021-1']
```

this is wrong because there is no 00 week number. week number starts from 1 to 52 and i also getting same 2021 instead of 2020. the output should be

```
['202114', '202113', '202112', '202111', '202110', '202109', '202108', '202107', '202106', '202105', '202104', '202103', '202102', '202101', '202053', '202052']
```

and so on if it is a leap year also it should work by changing the range and also need to parameterize the length of the range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Original Question:

I think the problem stems from working with `int` outputs of `.isocalendar()` instead of working inside of `datetime` objects which handle some of these issues.

Here is an example that subtracts off a week at a time using `datetime.timedelta(weeks=1)`:

```py
from datetime import date, timedelta

today = date.today()
weeks = []

for i in range(16):
    # Subtract a week from the initial 'today'
    today -= timedelta(weeks=1)

    # This handles some formatting to make it consistent with expected output:
    year, week, _ = today.isocalendar()
    weeks.append(str(year) + "{0:02d}".format(week))

print(weeks)
```

Expected output:

```
['202114', '202113', '202112', '202111', '202110', '202109', '202108', '202107', '202106', '202105', '202104', '202103', '202102', '202101', '202053', '202052']
```

### Modified Question:

The question changed to focus on how to get a '*list of dates between a start and end number*', where `start` and `end` are a number of weeks.

To do this: you can first subtract off the number of `start` weeks; then loop through the remaining weeks between `range(start, end)`, subtracting off one week at a time.

```py
from datetime import date, timedelta


def get_list_of_weeks(start, end):

    today = date.today()
    today -= timedelta(weeks=start)

    weeks = []
    for _ in range(start, end):
        today -= timedelta(weeks=1)

        # This handles some formatting to make it consistent with expected output:
        year, week, _ = today.isocalendar()
        weeks.append(str(year) + "{0:02d}".format(week))

    return weeks


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(list_of_weeks(10, 17))
```

Expected output:

```
['202104', '202103', '202102', '202101', '202053', '202052', '202051']
```

Answer (score 1):

I really went through a lot of documents and found your answer.
Check it took really a lot of time.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta


def getweeks(limit):
    finalres = []
    for i in range(limit):
        dt = date.today() - timedelta(weeks=i)
        year,month,d = dt.year,dt.month,dt.day
        week = str(date(year, month, d).isocalendar()[1])
        res = str(year) + week
        finalres.append(res)
    return finalres

num = int(input("Enter how many weeks you want ? : "))
print(getweeks(num))
```

This answer needs upvote :)

Comment: Sorry for the mistake i have modified the question my list should start from current week number -1 so current week number is 15 so it should start from 14 and also for week numbers in single digits i need a zeros. your code will return something like 20219 but i need 202109

Comment: Hey, For some of the single-digit month it gives the like that else it will give properly. this is because the number return by the time delta function is like that. but you got the answer so you can just modify it a little bit. like just using if and littering to all number and len is smaller than at 0 at so and so index.